# Does building a Delphi project with MSBuild create .Net dependencies?

Tags: .net, delphi, msbuild, dependencies

This may be a stupid question, as I'm not sure how MSBuild works with Delphi under the hood, but we have a Delphi app that needs to run with no .Net dependencies, and since we have updated our build process (now using team build with msbuild) the app won't run without .Net. I am just trying to narrow things down, so I'd appreciate any help you guys can provide...

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try to trim down the app into a reproducible case?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The last couple versions of Delphi have used MSBuild for the IDE, and the apps it produces don't have .NET dependencies, so the answer is no, in the general case at least.  It could be that something specific in your build process is introducing them, though...

Answer (score 8):

The [Microsoft Build Engine (MSBuild)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171452.aspx) is a build platform for Microsoft Windows.  With MSBuild, you can create a set of configurations to be used as build targets. Although msbuild it is an .net application (required .Net Framework installed), **this does not insert any .Net code or .NET dependencies into your executable**.

You can use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to check the dependecies of your exe.

Bye.

Answer (score 7):

So to be clear:  the answer to your question is:

No

Answer (score 0):

MsBuild ultimately calls DCC32 (Delphi Command Line Compiler). So it has absolutely nothing to do with .NET.